# How do I run a flask app in gunicorn if I used the application factory pattern?

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I wrote a flask app using the application factory pattern.  That means it doesn't create an app instance automatically when you import it.  You have to call create_app for that.  Now how do I run it in gunicorn?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Create a file `wsgi.py` under your project with the following contents, then point Gunicorn at it.

```
from my_project import create_app

app = create_app()
```

```
gunicorn -w 4 my_project.wsgi:app
# -w 4 specifies four worker processes
```

If you're using the application factory pattern, Gunicorn allows specifying a function call like `my_project:create_app()`. For most cases, you can the skip making a `wsgi.py` file and tell Gunicorn how to create your app directly.

```
gunicorn -w 4 "my_project:create_app()"
```

Note that the quotes are necessary in some shells where parentheses have special meaning.

Answer (score 11):

You need to `create_app()` with specific factory config in `run.py`. See the code below:

```
from your_app import create_app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'dev')
    app.run()
```

And then, you could run command `gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 run:create_app('dev')` to run the application.