# Gunicorn does't serve the flask app

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I have an issue to serve my flask app with gunicorn on ubuntu 16 (google computer engine instance).

I used the application factory pattern to create the app so, from my virtualenv, I've started gunicorn with the following instruction

```
gunicorn -w 3 "app:create_app()" --bind 0.0.0.0:8080
```

It seems that guniconr run correctly but I'm not able to reach the website. 
I create the istance allowing HTTP trafic but I don't know if I have to define a specific firewall rule or if the problem is somewhere else.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does it work locally?
Please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25319752/3975711

Comment: Yes the app works locally. I've already read that post but my understanding is that I can avoid to create the wsgi.py file and run the app directly with the script that I've shared in my post. Is it correct?